# How can get a list of UTC by country code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs, date-fns, moment-timezone

I have objects like this:

```
{ code: 'bg', name: 'Bulgaria' }, 
{ code: 'pl', name: 'Poland' },
{ code: 'it', name: 'Italy' },
....
```

How I can get a UTC list for each one?
For example, I need two formats:

1. **Available UTC for BG**: UTC +1, UTC +2 etc.
2. **Current local time**: Austrian time 11:00 UTC +1

Comment: Be aware, countries can cover more than 1 timezone!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library or an API that can provide the time zone information for each country code. One possible library is pytz, which is a Python package that provides access to the IANA time zone database. One possible API is WorldTimeAPI, which is a web service that returns the current time and time zone for a given location.

To use pytz, you need to install it with pip or another package manager. Then you can import it and use the country_timezones function to get a list of time zone names for each country code. For example:

```py
import pytz

countries = [
    { "code": "bg", "name": "Bulgaria" }, 
    { "code": "pl", "name": "Poland" },
    { "code": "it", "name": "Italy" },
]

for country in countries:
    timezones = pytz.country_timezones(country["code"])
    print(f"Available UTC for {country['name']}: {', '.join(timezones)}")
```

This will output something like:

```
Available UTC for Bulgaria: Europe/Sofia
Available UTC for Poland: Europe/Warsaw
Available UTC for Italy: Europe/Rome
```

To get the current local time for each time zone, you can use the datetime module and the localize function from pytz. For example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

countries = [
    { "code": "bg", "name": "Bulgaria" }, 
    { "code": "pl", "name": "Poland" },
    { "code": "it", "name": "Italy" },
]

for country in countries:
    timezones = pytz.country_timezones(country["code"])
    for timezone in timezones:
        tz = pytz.timezone(timezone)
        local_time = datetime.now(tz)
        print(f"Current local time for {country['name']} in {timezone}: {local_time.strftime('%H:%M')} {tz.utcoffset(local_time)}")
```

This will output something like:

```
Current local time for Bulgaria in Europe/Sofia: 13:00 +02:00
Current local time for Poland in Europe/Warsaw: 12:00 +01:00
Current local time for Italy in Europe/Rome: 12:00 +01:00
```

To use WorldTimeAPI, you need to make a GET request to the endpoint [http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip/{ip_address}](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/ip/%7Bip_address%7D) or [http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/{area}/{location}](http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/%7Barea%7D/%7Blocation%7D), where {ip_address} is the IP address of the user or the server, and {area} and {location} are the names of the time zone. You can use the requests module or another HTTP client to make the request and parse the JSON response. For example:

```py
import requests

countries = [
    { "code": "bg", "name": "Bulgaria" }, 
    { "code": "pl", "name": "Poland" },
    { "code": "it", "name": "Italy" },
]

for country in countries:
    response = requests.get(f"http://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Europe/{country['name']}")
    data = response.json()
    print(f"Available UTC for {country['name']}: {data['utc_offset']}")
    print(f"Current local time for {country['name']}: {data['datetime']}")
```

This will output something like:

```
Available UTC for Bulgaria: +02:00
Current local time for Bulgaria: 2021-03-04T13:00:35.837867+02:00
Available UTC for Poland: +01:00
Current local time for Poland: 2021-03-04T12:00:35.837867+01:00
Available UTC for Italy: +01:00
Current local time for Italy: 2021-03-04T12:00:35.837867+01:00
```

The advantage of using WorldTimeAPI is that you don't need to install any library or maintain any database, but the disadvantage is that you depend on an external service that may have limitations or errors. The advantage of using pytz is that you have more control and flexibility over the time zone data, but the disadvantage is that you need to install and update the library and handle any exceptions or edge cases.